# What to do with completely bad geometry?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.1

I have downloaded a shapefile that I need from a website. However, the geographic coordinate system is in a projected coordinate system WGS84 Major Auxiliary Sphere and it is projected in WGS84 Web Mercator (picture attached).

Does anyone know of a way to preserve the polygons within the file but convert this to WGS84 or a geographic coordinate system with only one projection so the polygons are useful?

I have also tried reprojecting to WGS84 (transformation WGS_1984_Major_Auxilary_Sphere_To_WGS_1984) but I get an error saying

> ERROR 000365: Invalid geographic transformation.

I understand that I should not define the projection since it is not what the file was originally created in, but did try it just in case and the polygons within the file disappeared. Does anyone know how to get this polygon file into the WGS84 geographic coordinate system? I would prefer it to not have a projection.

Is this problem solvable or do I need a new version from the creator?

[image]

Comment: "I have tried defining the projection to WGS84" that probably your problem, you need to re-project not to assign a new coordinate system

Comment: GIS software, and IT in general, doesn't like it when you assert untrue information. Defining a replacement for the correct coordinate system with an incorrect one does not work. There is no such thing as a "double projected shapefile." By definition, every projected coordinate system (PCS) must defined with respect to a geographic coordinate system (GCS) which critically defines the datum for the basis of comparison to other GCS. Please [Edit] your question to specify the details of your reprojection procedure and the layer extents before and after conversion.

Comment: Is the file freely available from some website? Can you share a link?

Comment: @Miro yes, https://tpwd.texas.gov/gis/#data (at the bottom under artificial reefs)

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what transformation you provided to the reprojection attempt.

Answer (score 4):

Holy mackerel, that's an old dataset. Its coordinate reference system (CRS) has been deprecated in favor of one that's easier to work with. That happened years ago. Its well-known ID (WKID) is EPSG:3785 AKA Esri:102113.

Step 1: Use the Define Projection Tool to change its CRS to 3857. You can type in the number in the search box. The name will look similar, but it will be based upon the standard WGS84 geographic CRS.

Step 2: Use the Project Tool to convert to 4326, WGS 1984.

Disclosure: I work for Esri, specifically on coordinate reference systems and transformations. I'm also on the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG registry.